# saving bash shell errors to file

Tags: unix, bash, freebsd, shell-script

I'm trying to save the errors when I do a `chmod` to a file. I am running the command:

```
chmod -R 766 * > chmod-errors.txt
```

But that does not work. I also tried

```
chmod -R 766 * | cat > chmod-errors.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are redirecting the standard output of the command, not the error output. You need to redirect the error output to the file.

```
chmod -R 766 * 2> chmod-errors.txt
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055 For more reference material and a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks @honk, worked great. And thanks @Nitrodist for the background info! I appreciate it VERY much!